# Meteor global template helpers not working in all templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm running into an issue where my global template helper is working in one template but not in another. It's a helper to display the profile image associated with a user in their post and on their profile page. The image displays on posts and even updates when a new profile image is uploaded by the user. However, it's not working on the user's profile page.

The code for the helper is as follows

```
Template.registerHelper('getProfileImg', function(userId){
  var imgUrl = UserImages.findOne({userId: userId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).image;
  return imgUrl;
});
```

I have this stored in client/common.js

I'm accessing it in the posts page like so;

```
{{#each posts}}
<div class="row post z-depth-2">
  <div class="col s1">
    <img class="post-image" src="{{getProfileImg userId}}" />
  </div>

  <div class="col s11">
    <small>Posted By {{name}} at {{createdAt}}</small>
    <blockquote>
      {{body}}
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
{{else}}
  <p>
    No Posts Yet
  </p>
{{/each}}
```

Here it works fine. It's not working though when I access it from the user profile page like below:

```
<div class="col s6">
 <img src="{{getProfileImg userId}}" alt="ProfileImg" />
</div>
```

Any ideas on what may be happening?

Comment: In the first example userId is a property of a post. I'm assuming that on your profile page userId is not a valid property of the user profile. You probably need to use _id on the profile page.

Comment: Would I then be replacing userId with just _id? Will I have to modify the helper afterwards?

Comment: You need to replace it with whichever user's id you are trying to get the profile image for.

Comment: that's because you forgot to create helper for `<div class="col s6">`